# How to force parent div to expand by child div width/padding/margin/box?

Tags: html, css

I want to expand div parent with child div but I don't know if that's possible and how to do it.

[image]

I prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrfaE/) and included some code.

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: gray;
}
div.page {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    max-width: 72em;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1em;
}
div.one {
    background-color: red;
    width: 40%;
}
div.two {
    background-color: green;
    width: 120%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="one">One</div>
        <div class="two">Two</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're asking the child to be wider than its parent (width: 120%).  Are you trying to create a CSS paradox?

Comment: @PatriceLevesque I can have wrong understand of CSS - tell me more. Is it impossible to set width of parent by children in such way? It width calculated from parent to child (so it is not possible in reverse way? Should I set parent width larger to keep child inside it if it require more space (min-width)?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. The padding:1em in your div.page(parent) is the one that controls the width of your div.two(child). see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CrfaE/6/

Comment: Or what are you trying to do is to make the width of div.two reach the end of the parent div.page on the right side without a space? because below answer is already correct base on my understanding.

Comment: By the way, can I ask why you are using an XHTML namespace but an HTML content-type? XHTML and HTML should not be mixed; there are too many distinct differences.

Comment: @bot I want resize parent by content but I think it will not works I was excepted 120% lead infinity what is impossible. I think more about some em size now i.e. 120 em and how to handle it?

Comment: @MrLister Do you mean `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` as html use?

Comment: @Chameleon Yes, in the example, the `<html>` start tag has `xmlns` and `xml:lang` attributes, defining the document as XHTML, but the meta element says the document as html. This is contradictory! In most cases, the browsers will ignore conflicting settings like this, but it pays to be consistent. Either XHTML all the way, or (recommended) HTML all the way.

Comment: @MrLister Looks you are right with contradiction need to think about it again - XHTML is bad since if you use external AJAX/JS it can leads to errors I think so - it not possible to achieve XTHML.

Comment: XHTML is not bad! Not bad at all, but it just has some stricter rules than most people are willing to put up with.

Comment: @MrLister XHTML is bad for people since they do mistakes and achieve 100% of xml is hardcore - consider you have inclusion for Google, Facebook, XXX, ... - how you can control that this will be XHTML (impossible is not it)? How fast they solve bug - if they will solve ... I prefer XHTML but till browsers will not force XHTML it will be impossible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32328/discussion-between-chameleon-and-mr-lister)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The key solution to your problem is to use `display:inline-block;`

**HTML**

```css
body {
    background: gray;
}
div.page {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.one {
    background-color: red;
    width: 10em;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.two {
    background-color: green;
    width: 40em;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i know it is old, but if you need IE7 support, use `display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;`

Comment: this is what I needed... now ... to understand the WHY... anyone?

Comment: A block element will claim the horizontal space that the parent has to offer whereas an inline-block will take the horizontal space it needs to display the content (unless overridden). If the inline-block is bigger than the parent, it will overflow.

You can make a block element to evaluate content width by setting `width: fit-content` however that is not IE compatible.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use % and expect box to overflow, else it never ends 100% turns 120%, but then 120% of 120%, becomes .. and so on. forget this idea, it cannot work.

Your CSS request is incoherent.

Beside, to see an element to grow wider than window, one of the parent must be able to behave this way, mostly , content overflow and remain visible. (html/body or parent)

as far as i know only:

```
display:
```

1. `table`
2. `inline-table`
3. `table-row`
4. `table-cell`

Can let container grow as much as content does.

Comment: This is very interesting and useful to know. I have used `display: table` only very sparingly in the past

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
div.two {
        background-color: green;
        width: 120%;
}
```

You are telling the child to be 120% the width of the parent, which is to say, the entire width plus 20% more. Make it 100% and you should get the expected result..

Comment: I can have wrong understand of CSS - tell me more. Is it impossible to set width of parent by children in such way? It width calculated from parent to child (so it is not possible in reverse way? Should I set parent width larger to keep child inside it if it require more space (min-width)?

Comment: IT sure seems like you have it worng. 100% of an element is the entire thing, if you set it to more than 100% it is the whole width, plus whatever number. If you fill a glass with water, but have 120% of the volume of the glass, it will fill all the way to the top and then the remaining 20% will spill over. :)

Comment: It means that I should set parent width to i.e. 80em if I want keep inside children with width less than 80em - and it always 81em children will overflow (not resize parent).

Comment: Depends on your EM setting but yes. Also it depends on the styles you have applied to the parent. By default they should resize to containe their parents, but if you have a set width or some overflow properties that will hinder it.

Comment: @Chameleon That is confusing. What do you want the child width to be? 80em? If so, then it's easy: just `float` the parent, then it will adjust itself to its children's width. But that is impossible with a child width of `120%`. Forget about the `120%`. It won't work.

Comment: There is no need to float the parent.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks There are other solutions of course (inline-block for instance, or just set the width if you know what the exact width of the child is).

Comment: @MrLister I think the best will be to know child width and design min-width since it very natural - what you think about it?

Comment: @Chameleon If that is an option, yes. It depends on your situation.

Comment: @MrLister I want design layout from html->body->div->div-> ... so able to control width need little calculations on em :) Now I am better understand flow thanks for helpful hints.

Comment: Divs by defualt occupy 100% width of its parent, and it always has a parent. As Mr. Lister says, forget about 120% width, that will spill over the width of the parent. You will have to calculate the width but do not go over 100% (or 72em)